# Pyspark Array Column - Replace Empty Elements with Default Value

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, regexp-replace

I have a dataframe with a column which is an array of strings. Some of the elements of the array may be missing like so:

```
-------------|-------------------------------
ID           |array_list                      
---------------------------------------------
38292786     |[AAA,, JLT]                    |
38292787     |[DFG]                          |
38292788     |[SHJ, QKJ, AAA, YTR, CBM]      |
38292789     |[DUY, ANK, QJK, POI, CNM, ADD] |
38292790     |[]                             |
38292791     |[]                             |
38292792     |[,,, HKJ]                      |
```

I would like to replace the missing elements with a default value of "ZZZ". Is there a way to do that? I tried the following code, which is using a transform function and a regular expression:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

def transform(self, f):
    return f(self)

DataFrame.transform = transform  
  
df = df.withColumn("array_list2", F.expr("transform(array_list, x -> regexp_replace(x, '', 'ZZZ'))"))
```

This doesn't give an error but it is producing nonsense. I'm thinking I just don't know the correct way to identify the missing elements of the array - can anyone help me out?

In production our data has around 10 million rows and I am trying to avoid using explode or a UDF (not sure if it's possible to avoid using both though, just need the code run as efficiently as possible). I'm using Spark 2.4.4

This is what I would like my output to look like:

```
-------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------
ID           |array_list                     | array_list2
---------------------------------------------|-------------------------------
38292786     |[AAA,, JLT]                    |[AAA, ZZZ, JLT]                     
38292787     |[DFG]                          |[DFG]                          
38292788     |[SHJ, QKJ, AAA, YTR, CBM]      |[SHJ, QKJ, AAA, YTR, CBM]      
38292789     |[DUY, ANK, QJK, POI, CNM, ADD] |[DUY, ANK, QJK, POI, CNM, ADD] 
38292790     |[]                             |[ZZZ]                             
38292791     |[]                             |[ZZZ]   
38292792     |[,,, HKJ]                      |[ZZZ, ZZZ, ZZZ, HKJ]
```

Comment: Did you tried with something like regexp_replace(x, '^(?![\s\S])', 'ZZZ')?

Comment: @ggagliano, interestingly, using that adds ZZZ as a prefix to all the non-missing elements!

Comment: Ahaha nice! Then try to remove the ^ at the beginning

Comment: The statement of the UDF is not really an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of something, but i'm not sure if it is efficient.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("array_list2", F.split(F.array_join("array_list", ",", "ZZZ"), ","))
```

First I concatenate the values as a string with a delimiter `,` (hoping you don't have it in your string but you can use something else). I use the `null_replacement` option to fill the `null` values. Then I split according to the same delimiter.

---

**EDIT**: Based on @thebluephantom comment, you can try this solution :

```py
df.withColumn(
    "array_list_2", F.expr(" transform(array_list, x -> coalesce(x, 'ZZZ'))")
).show()
```

SQL built-in [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) is not working for me, so I couldn't try it but hopefully you'll have the result you wanted.

Comment: in scala, you can use transform but it is not available in python apparently. Otherwise, UDF.

Comment: transform does exist in pyspark.

Comment: @thebluephantom this [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) or this [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#transform[U](t:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) ?

Comment: df = df.withColumn("knownLanguages2", F.expr(" transform(knownLanguages, x -> upper(x))"))

Comment: Hmm. This is placing each individual character as an element in the new array column (e.g., [A, A, A, |,  Z, Z, Z, |, J, L, T]). But it did get rid of my empty value so I think you may be on the right track, I will play around with this code. Thanks!

Comment: @tallmary did you try both solutions ? the one with the `split` and the one with the `transofrm`?

Comment: @tallmary Try again with the new version. actually `|` is a regexp token, I switch for the `,` try and let me know.

Comment: @Steven thank you!!! yes the switch from | to , got it working! thank you so much this is great!! Your alternate solution also works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex_replace works at character level.

I could not get it to work with transform either, but with help from the first answerer I used a UDF - not that easy.

Here is my example with my data, you can tailor.

```
%python

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

concat_udf = udf(
    lambda con_str, arr: [
        x if x is not None else con_str for x in arr or [None]
    ],
    ArrayType(StringType()),
)

arrayData = [
        ('James',['Java','Scala']),
        ('Michael',['Spark','Java',None]),
        ('Robert',['CSharp','']),
        ('Washington',None),
        ('Jefferson',['1','2'])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=arrayData, schema = ['name','knownLanguages'])
df = df.withColumn("knownLanguages", concat_udf(lit("ZZZ"), col("knownLanguages")))
df.show()
```

returns:

```
+----------+------------------+
|      name|    knownLanguages|
+----------+------------------+
|     James|     [Java, Scala]|
|   Michael|[Spark, Java, ZZZ]|
|    Robert|        [CSharp, ]|
|Washington|             [ZZZ]|
| Jefferson|            [1, 2]|
+----------+------------------+
```

Quite tough this, had some help from the first answerer.

Comment: You asked a question on how to write the UDF to answer another question using both my answers ? XD

Comment: So, u got 25 pts for something that I knew was possible but I knew not yet how to do and must be possible and could be applicable here as opposed to transform. So, what's the big deal? People use eachother's work. It's called reusability, like API's. Welcome to the real world.

Comment: That's not a critic, I just think it is funny, and you did it well :)

Comment: I was most appreciative of your input.